# Como escanear vulnerabilidades en base de datos oracle conectada a aplicacion desktop?

Tags: oracle, seguridad

Estoy usando la distribución Kali-Linux para auditorias de seguridad que estoy haciendo en mi proyecto, en las aplicaciones web si he podido auditar bien, pero ahora el caso:
 Tengo una aplicación de escritorio para Windows que se conecta con una BD Oracle, sin embargo, en Kali no encuentro ninguna herramienta para probar vulnerabilidades en la BD para este tipo de escenario, alguien ha podido realizar este tipo de pruebas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Kali hay una herramienta **Oscanner**, sirve para hacer test a bases Oracle.
[Oscanner info Kali](https://tools.kali.org/vulnerability-analysis/oscanner)